# How to make a module discoverable using index.ts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module

I'm trying typescript in my project and in my earlier projects, if I've a `React` component then I'll make my project structure as :

```
componentDir/
    Component.js
    index.js
```

Where my `index.js` would contain the contents as :

```
import Component from './Component';

export default Component;
```

I'd use this component (or any module with `index` file) anywhere as :

```
import Component from './componentDir';
```

How can I achieve similar thing with TypeScript?

Comment: The exact same code above should work in TypeScript.  Did you try it and run into a problem?

Comment: I want my `componentDir` to have `index.ts` file, instead `index.js` and it is not working.

Comment: If I do `import Component from './componentDir/index.ts';` then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/).

in the case that you setup is success, you could do it the following:

Project:

```
|- /components/
   footerComponent.ts
|- index.ts
|- tsconfig.json
|- webpack.config.js
```

Declaring component:

```
import React from 'react';

export class FooterComponent  extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
   }
}
```

Importing:

```
import FooterComponent './components/footerComponent'
```

tsconfig:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "outDir": "./dist/",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "strictNullChecks": true,
   "module": "es6",
   "jsx": "react",
   "target": "es5",
   "allowJs": true
},
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "useBabel": true,
  "useCache": true
},
"include": [
  "../src/**/*",
  "./global.d.ts"
 ]
}
```

Have a good day.

Comment: I'm using `awesome-typescript-loader` and it is not working

Comment: Also, I'm using `webpack4`

Comment: ok, tell me, what error do you have? here is the documentation : 

https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: Hi @ene_salinas, it is giving me one error as `A dynamic import call in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.`, can you help me with that. Although it is not giving me module import error now

Comment: I've target as "es6" in my `tsconfig` file so I'm not giving any `--lib` options but it is still giving me this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182365/discussion-between-ene-salinas-and-ajay-gaur).